# When trying to edit data the view is getting updated without submit form Angular 11

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am facing strange issue. The data from `upsert-objective.component.ts` is automatically transfer to `objectives.component.ts`

I have a main component where I am using router-outlet for `objectives.compoennt.ts` called `group-setting.component.ts`.

group-settings.component.ts

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="example-container">
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav position="end" (closed)="sidenavClosed()">
        <app-upsert-objective [editData]="editableObjectiveData" *ngIf="showInviteBar == 'showUpsertObjective'" (sideNavStatus)="sidenav.close()"></app-upsert-objective>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content>
........

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
............
```

(objectives.component.html)

```
        <div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let item of objectives; let i = index">
            <div class="card objective_item">
            <div class="objective_graphic dfc">
                <img [src]="item.icon" [alt]="item.title">
                <div class="dfc">
                    <div class="wrpbtn">
                        <button mat-button (click)="editObjective(item, i)"><mat-icon svgIcon="edit"></mat-icon></button>
                    </div>
                    <span class="checkbox_wrap">
                        <mat-checkbox color="primary" [(ngModel)]="item.checked" (change)="updateCheckbox($event, item.id)"></mat-checkbox>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="objective_content">
                <h2 class="dfc">{{item.title}}</h2>
                    <div class="benefit_panel">
                        <h4 class="small">BENEFITS</h4>
                        <ul class="style-3" *ngIf="item.benefits.length; else noData">
                            <li *ngFor="let benefit of item.benefits"> <mat-icon svgIcon="check_circle_outline"></mat-icon> {{benefit}}</li>
                        </ul>
                        <ng-template #noData>No Benefit available</ng-template>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

objectives.component.ts

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getObjectivesByCommunity();
  }
  getObjectivesByCommunity(){
    var communityId = this.loginUser.communityInfo.id;
    this._objectivesApi.getObjectivesByCommunity(communityId, 100).pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe(result=> {
        this.objectives = result;
    });
  }
  editObjective(data, i){
    data['order_id'] = i;
    this._setting.setUpsertObjective(data);
  }
```

setting.service.ts

```
  public upsertObjective = new Subject<any>();
  constructor() { }

  setUpsertObjective(status){
    this.upsertObjective.next(status);
  }
```

upsert-objective.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="upsertObjective" (ngSubmit)="onSubmits()">
            <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                <mat-label>Title *:</mat-label>
                <input [formControlName]="'title'" matInput placeholder="Enter Objective Title">
                <mat-error *ngIf="(f.title.touched || submitted) && f.title?.errors">
                    <div *ngIf="f.title?.errors?.required">Title is required</div>
                </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                <mat-label>Description *:</mat-label>
                <textarea [formControlName]="'description'" matInput placeholder="Enter Description"></textarea>
                <mat-error *ngIf="(f.description.touched || submitted)  && f.description?.errors">
                    <div *ngIf="f.description?.errors?.required">Description is required</div>
                </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                <mat-label>Icon *:</mat-label>
                <input [formControlName]="'icon'" matInput placeholder="Enter Icon Url">
                <mat-error *ngIf="(f.icon.touched || submitted) && f.icon?.errors">
                    <div *ngIf="f.icon?.errors?.required">Icon url is required</div>
                </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                <mat-label>Benefit :</mat-label>
                <input [formControlName]="'benefits'" [(ngModel)]="benefitValue" matInput placeholder="Enter Benefit"> <button mat-button>Add Benefit</button>
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-list class="benefit_list_edit" *ngIf="updatedBenefits.length">
                <p *ngFor="let item of updatedBenefits; let i = index">{{item}} <a href="javascript:void(0)" mat-button (click)="deleteBenefit(i, $event)"> <mat-icon svgIcon="delete"></mat-icon></a> </p>
            </mat-list>
            <div class="col-span-9">
                <button type="submit" [disabled]="upsertObjective.disabled" class="btn btn-light-success">{{title == 'Add' ? 'Add' : 'Update'}}</button>
                <button type="button" *ngIf="title=='Edit'" (click)="cancelEdit()" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</button>
                <button type="reset" *ngIf="title=='Add'" class="btn btn-secondary">Reset</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

upsert-objective.component.ts

I didn't include the form submit code because the issue occurs before form submit when that benefit section is added inside the form.

```
  updateBenefit(){
    if(this.benefitValue != "" && this.benefitValue != null) {
      this.updatedBenefits.push(this.benefitValue);
      console.log(this.editData )//this @Input variable is getting updated when benefit is updated.
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.benefitValue = "";  
      }, 100);
    }
  }

  cancelEdit() {
    this.closeSideNav(true);
  }

  deleteBenefit(index, event){
    event.preventDefault();
    this.updatedBenefits.splice(index, 1);
  }
  updatedEditData(){

    if(this.editData && typeof this.editData == 'object') {
        this.title = "Edit";
        this.upsertObjective.patchValue({
          title: this.editData.title,
          description : this.editData.description,
          icon: this.editData.icon
        })
        this.objectiveId = this.editData.id;
        this.updatedBenefits = this.editData.benefits;
        
    } else {
      this.title = 'Add';
    }
  }
```

[image: without submit data get updated.]

How do I avoid data being updated in the view before submit. Its really strange.

Small video demo what I am trying to explain.
[Issue video recording](https://www.loom.com/share/9de481066cfb4230886b8ee736b940e5)

Comment: You obviously share the same variable in 2 components. If you don't want to share the data, you have to make a copy...

Comment: I am not sharing same variable. This issue comes when I am trying to edit the objective and transfer the single objective data from objective component -> group setting and then append it to child component via parent to child data sharing. After that I am trying to get that data at upsert page. That's it. I do not see same variable any where. but while the component are view encapsulated I don't think even the same variable would have made such problem. (there is no same variable.)

Comment: Well, you do share variable references, and doing `this.updatedBenefits.push(this.benefitValue);` will update the initial variable content. You may use spread operator to make a new array: `this.updatedBenefits = [...this.updatedBenefits, this.benefitValue];`, so it makes a new reference, and does not alter the previous array.

Comment: You are right. I updated this code `this.updatedBenefits = [...this.editData.benefits]` at updatedEditData() function at upsert-objective.component.ts and it fixed.

Comment: @Santosh you need new reference for objects or array in order to angular detect changes in your project. [...this.editData] will give you new reference and angular runs its change detection

Comment: so my solution still a issue or I need to make entire new object ?

Comment: Its okay. if it works right for you now.